# Python: I am trying to rename (chop off) the last 15 characters from filenames in a single directory

Tags: python

Python: I am trying to rename (chop off) the last 15 characters from all files in a single folder without chopping up 'mychoppingfile.py'.  Also, the program must only run one time for each file (i guess this would be handled by moving the output files to a new directory after processing?).  This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
files = os.listdir('.')
for filename in files:
    os.rename(filename, filename[:-15])
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is using a dictionary:

```
import os
files = os.listdir('.')
seen = dict()
for filename in files:
  if len(filename) > 15 and filename != 'mychoppingfile.py':
    tofile = filename[:-15]
    if tofile not in seen:
      print filename + " -> " + filename[:-15]
      seen[tofile] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify the problem you're facing.

Anyway, notice that if your filenames are shorter than 16 characters, then you'll be trying to rename them to the empty string, which is of course wrong. Maybe that's the problem.

Other thing it's bad there is you may be also renaming the script itself.

Comment: i know, duh.  i realized that after i posted --tnks.

Comment: how would I exclude any file which ends with alpha (a letter)?

Answer (score 0):

```
exclude = ['mychoppingfile.py'] # could add more exclusions to this list
for filename in files:  # see notes below
    if not filename in exclude:
        os.rename(filename, filename[:-15])
```

However there are a lot of problems:

- Should use `os.walk` to get just the files
- Need to handle case where filename is less than 16 chars
- Need to handle case where the filename truncation causes a collision (either with an existing filename or another collision in this pass)